# css3 loader alignment in breadcrumb

Tags: html, css, alignment, loader

I have place a css loader div inside breadcrumb menu but the loader is pushing the text down.
How do I get the loader and the text in the same line.

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/jFAyX/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make .loader inline-block

```css
​.loader{display:inline-block;}​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jFAyX/5/)

Comment: But .loder class is already there in css file, if i add the display:inline-block to that existing class it is not working. It works wen I add new line again like how u have added. Is there any way to get it for existing class only?

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/jFAyX/6/ . It doesn't matter if its in a new line or not, I just didn't want to look for the existing line of .loader

Answer (score 0):

You could style you loader like this:

```
.loader{
    width:13px; height:16px; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Absolute positioning makes it possible to position the element in relation to a non static positioned parent, and without it interfering with static positioned siblings. It's position will start at where it would be positioned if it was static. I moved it a little to the left, using a negative left margin, so that it wouldn't cover the breadcrumb text.